# Does anyone have a list of the Delphi IDE macros?

Tags: delphi, ide, path, macros

I know about $(Delphi) and $EDNAME but after much seaching I cant find a list of these and any others for use in libary path names etc.
Can anyone oblige please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the information on [this page](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesDelphi14) is 100% complete, but it's very useful never-the-less.

It provides a list of macro names (as they are called) and some examples of usage.  The page makes reference to reproducing the information from the Delphi Help, but I couldn't find this information (easily) in the BDS 2006 help system.  However, within the IDE itself, when you add/edit a "Tool" via the **Tools > Configure Tools** menu, the list of supported macros and a brief description is provided.

Note that in addition to these macro names (only recognised, afaik, in the "Tools > Configure Tools" part of the IDE), any environment variable may be identified using the same/similar syntax in path/directory fields of various IDE settings:

```
$(ENV)   << substitutes value of environment value named "ENV"
```